# on conflict postgresql statement works with joins?

Tags: postgresql

I am using `on conflict` statement to do an upsert, but I get an error: `Syntax error near to line 58: ON CONFLICT (id_producto_final) DO`.

The query statement is:

```
     Insert into table1 (id, value1, description, isactivated)
     select a.id, b.value1, c.description, d.isactivated
     from tableA as a
     left join tableB as b on b.id=a.id1
     left join tableC as c on c.id=a.id2
     left join tableD as d on d.id=a.id3
     ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET isactivated= EXCLUDED.isactivated
```

It neither works with `do nothing`, so is not `excluded table` error. So I am guessing that maybe are joins the error source, but I do no even know why.

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you run it on after 9.5?..

Comment: @VaoTsun 9.4.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

> ON CONFLICT can be used to specify an alternative action to raising a
>   unique constraint or exclusion constraint violation error. (See ON
>   CONFLICT Clause below.)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html - no such option. `ON CONFLICT` is interpreted starting from 9.5

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html

> Major enhancements in PostgreSQL 9.5 include:
>
> Allow INSERTs that would generate constraint conflicts to be turned
>   into UPDATEs or ignored

Comment: Thanks Vao! What alternatives exists for 9.4?